# MariaDB on Debian: Syntax error: How to switch unix socket authentication back to password-based?

Tags: mysql, unix, mariadb, alter, unix-socket

I just installed Mariadb on my new unix system (Mariadb server version 10.1.37 Debian 9.6). I have the following users:

```
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+
| user       | authentication_string | plugin      | host      |
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+
| root       |                       | unix_socket | localhost |
| phpmyadmin |                       |             | localhost |
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want to be able to log in as 'root' with a password (and not by using the unix_socket plugin). I tried to change to password-based authentication using ALTER USER command. I enter MariaDB from the root-account using "sudo mysql". Then I tried each of the commands below:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';

MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA
mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';

MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA 
mysql_native_password;
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('mypassword');

MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH 
mysql_native_password;
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('mypassword');

MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 
mysql_native_password;
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('mypassword');
```

In all cases I get the following error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '...' at line 1.

What is the right syntax/way to change the root login from socket to password-based? Any help would be appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: `ALTER USER` was introduced in 10.2.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like You've fresh installed MariaDB or MySQL.

After installation You've to simply run following from root:

```
mysql_secure_install
```

or:

```
sudo mysql_secure_install
```

[More info here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_secure_installation/)

As I read manuals MariaDB has made auth socket feature.

So try to [uninstall plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#uninstalling-the-plugin):

```
UNINSTALL SONAME 'auth_socket';
```

and/or [switch](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#switching-to-password-based-authentication) to native password auth:

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password;
```

if it will not work also, so try to empty plugin field of user table and flush privileges:

```
USE mysql; 
UPDATE user SET plugin='' WHERE user ='root'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Yes, fresh installation, I ran mysql_secure_install yesterday. When asked "enter current password for root",I just pressed enter. Entering (sudo) mysql_secure_install on root now lead to "command not found"-> I ran again on root: sudo apt install mysql-server, which didn't change anything to installation but mysql_secure_install -command then was available again. Entered strong root password there, but still able to call mysql wo/ password, unix_socket still showing up as plugin for root user.

Comment: @MarcSteffen have You simply tried to update table? `USE mysql; UPDATE user SET plugin='' WHERE user = 'root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` also check this file for existence: `/root/.my.cnf` what if secure installation creates that file

Comment: @ num8er big thanks, you solved it: <code> USE mysql; UPDATE user SET plugin='' WHERE user ='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; </code> worked perfectly. My user shows up without the socket plugin and the strong root password previously entered with the mysql_secure_install-command is active.

Answer (score 1):

After sessions of safariing, exploring, finding and searching, these 3 commands help me for MariaDB case mentioned in this question:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &

UPDATE user SET plugin='' WHERE user ='root'; 

UPDATE mysql.user SET 
    authentication_string = PASSWORD('UNCOMPROMISABLE_STRONGHOLD_PASSWORD') 
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
```